# Android sms intercept or other server-less push ability

Tags: java, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

During the early days of windows mobile phones, (pre exchange server capabilities on mobile devices, and before gmail became what it is today) there was an app which for the life of me I can not remember the name. It provided PUSH notifications for email users by sending an sms to the device, which their application intercepted before it went to the messaging app, this sms was composed of a certain line of code that told the email software on the phone to poll the email server for new email. Of course this software also stopped the sms from actually reaching the text messaging application so as not to confuse the user.

Now let me put this into context. I am trying to create a note taking app for android devices that will allow one person to create a note that will then be automatically synced with other selected devices, such as family members, certain co-workers etc. I want this to sync automatically, and quietly, and the pre-requisite is that I do not want to have to set up a central server to handle the passthrough.

I had thought back to the app from the early 2000`s that I spoke of a moment ago, in thoughts that the user could just add certain contacts and their numbers into a group, write a note, then the application would send an SMS to each of the contacts that would be intercepted by the note app on their phones (due to the specific header in the SMS). The message would be blocked from reaching the messaging app. But would then initiate a file transfer in the background from the initiator to all of the client phones.

This is a circumstance that Ive found very hard to search for.

Is there any known api that could facilitate this? 
Or do any of you know a better method?
Will Google cloud messaging allow this to happen?

The file itself could be theoretically sent in the message, or the message could initiate
a P2P connection. Either way doesn't matter to me.

I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: It's 2013... almost 2014. Data is ubiquitous, and someone who owns a smart phone with your software installed, most likely has that data plan also. Regardless, as of Android 4.4 KitKat, SMS intercept is no longer possible, unless your app is the primary SMS app.

Comment: I intend to use mobile data, but I need a way to initiate push from one device to another with no middle man (server). user 1 creates note file, hits save, phone tickles other phones, other phones initiate p2p and retrieve file, other phones sound notification that note has been modified and synced. Im just looking for the method to initiate the p2p connection between multiple devices without having to set up a server.

Comment: Also, regarding your comment about kitkat, will this change mean that Tasker will no longer be able to intercept SMS for getting geolocations, initiating picture taking and other security things that you can do? I sure hope not, because that is one handy feature of tasked.

Comment: Never Mind, I just read over what nPn linked to. This seems unfortunate.

Comment: The post I attached below seems to indicate that apps should still be able to send and receive sms's as long as the user does not change the default sms app.

Comment: hmmm. Well the thing that worries me, I am currently running 4.4 cyanogen on my note 2 and it looks as if hangouts is it. Reading what you linked, I could still as you said send and receive messages from my app, but I could not block them from being passed to the sms app, and that kind of kills the idea, because a user wouldn't want to see a message with strange code in it. Looks like I'm back on the hunt again. I have server space, but just do not want to tie myself down to having to maintain a service for my app. I appreciate the input so far though. Everything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an api for this, but it was hidden.  As 323go mentions it is changing. As of kitkat it will be un-hidden.
Here is a post on the new api.http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1
If you search for sms broadcast receiver,  you should find some info on how to use the currently hidden api.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ive done some more research on Google Cloud Messaging. I was looking to see if I could simply embed parts of the server side code within each copy of the app to eliminate the need for the central server, and found that it in itself will not work for my wishes because my token id would have to be stored in-app for each person that has the app. Thus it could be decompiled and compromise the app security. I know Tasker for android has the ability to intercept SMS to initiate things for gps, and other security purposes, so I hope this info will get me closer.